# iOS App Crashes in Release mode on making api request using ServiceStack in .Net MAUI app

Tags: ios, servicestack, maui

I have integrated ServiceStack nuget package in .net maui app and making api request from it. It works fine in debug mode on ios platform, but in Release mode my app crashes. I'm not able to figure out what error it produces and why my app got crashed.

I have tried both ServiceStack Client and ServiceStack Http client packages but both does not work for me.

I have not linked the assemblies, also trim the assemblies that contain serializable types like this
`<ItemGroup> <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="ServiceStack.Client" /> </ItemGroup>`

[image: Here I have skip the required assembly]

But there's no progress at all. I still getting the `SIGABRT` error in my logs. Below you can have a look at the folder structure.

[image]